# Import Excel file into a myPhpAdmin MySQL database

Tags: excel, csv, import, phpmyadmin

So I am working on my extended essay that has to do with mysql databases. I want to create an excel spreadsheet with 100 or so books and then import then in to three database tables with different collation types. I have saved the excel file as a csv file and when i go to phpMyAdmin and click on import in my database, i get an error.

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '1,In Pharoah's Army,Tobias Wolff,NULL,NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL
> 2,MacBeth,William Sha' at line 1

How would i go about importing an excel spreadsheet into myPHPAdmin using the import function given, so that i can do this using GUI instead of codes, which i don't know much about.

I am using XAMPP to create a local server and the myPHPadmin server version is 5.1.44

Answer (score 0):

To import a XLS or XLSX file into MySQL using PHPMyAdmin can be done a number or ways. I have used CSV and OpenDocument Spreadsheet.

When importing a CSV file, make sure that the amount of columns in the sheet math your database otherwise this will throw an error. Be aware that CSV will remove all formatting in your sheet so potentially if your using an ISBN or barcode in your sheet it could cause problems when displayed in the database.

As for OpenDocument Spreadsheet, this will allow you to export your sheet into MySQL keeping your formats. Although this is good it does not name your columns and will always create a new table. This can be edited easily by creating your column names at the top of your spread sheet and then editing the table name in PHPMyAdmin. Be aware though that this is a bad method when exporting large spreadsheet it will probably time out.

So from your situation I would us OpenDocument Spreadsheet format which you can save as .ODS.

Hope this helps.